# Ideal generated by a regular sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

In [Boocher and Grifo - Lower bounds on Betti numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05871), in example 2.2 they say that if $R=k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is a polynomial ring and $M=R/(f_1,\dotsc,f_c)$ where $f_i$ form a regular sequence, then the minimal free resolution of $M$ is given by the Koszul complex. I know that it is a free resolution, but why is it a minimal free resolution?

I don't understand why it is true. Any reference or idea?

I think that theorem 3.10 may be interesting for this, can I assume that $f_i$ is homogeneous?

Comment: Yes, the $f_i$ are in fact homogeneous — this is not said explicitely in the paper, but the set-up is graded modules. Then the differentials of the Koszul complex are zero modulo the ideal $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and this implies that the resolution is minimal.